# Ошибка времени выполнения: Индекс находился вне границ массива. Inc(i)

Tags: pascalabc.net

Inc(i) выдаёт мне ошибку о выходе за границы массива, не понимаю что сделать надо

TextGen.pas(23) : Ошибка времени выполнения: Индекс находился вне границ массива.

```
program TextGenerator;

const
  max_words = 100;
  
type
  WordArray = array[1..max_words] of string;

function ReadWordsFromFile(filename: string): WordArray;
var
  fileHandle: Text;
  word: string;
  words: WordArray;
  i: integer;
begin
  assign(fileHandle, filename);
  reset(fileHandle);
  i := 1;
  while not Eof(fileHandle) do
  begin
    read(fileHandle, word);
    words[i] := word;
    Inc(i);  // В этом месте паскаль ругается
  end;
  close(fileHandle);
  ReadWordsFromFile := words;
end;

procedure PrintWords(words: WordArray);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to max_words do
  begin
    if words[i] <> '' then
      writeln(words[i])
    else
      break;
  end;
end;

procedure FindFollowingWords(words: WordArray; searchWord: string);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to max_words - 1 do
  begin
    if words[i] = searchWord then
      writeln(words[i + 1]);
  end;
end;

procedure CreateWordPairs(words: WordArray);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to max_words - 1 do
  begin
    if words[i] <> '' then
      writeln(words[i], ' (', words[i + 1], ')')
    else
      break;
  end;
end;

{ Main }
var
  words: WordArray;
  filename: string;
  searchWord: string;
begin
  filename := 'Garri.txt';
  words := ReadWordsFromFile(filename);
  
  writeln('Слова из файла: ');
  printWords(words);
  
  writeln('Введите слово для поиска следующих слов: ');
  readln(searchWord);
  FindFollowingWords(words, searchWord);
  
  writeln('Пары слов со следующим словом: ');
  CreateWordPairs(words);
end.
```

Файл Garri.txt это тупо книга с Гарри Поттером, откуда слова вытягиваются

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (**«почему этот код не работает?»**) должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и *минимальный код* для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что размер массива равен 100, а книга должна вмещать куда больше слов, чем 100. Так, что когда переменная "i" становится равной 101 и в массив идет попытка вставит очередное слово по индексу 101 (words[101] := word;), то это и вызывает ошибку выхода за пределы массива.